# Why wasn't this main character injured in Spider-Man: No Way Home?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-no-way-home

In *Spider-Man: No Way Home (2021)*, during the battle at

> the Statue of Liberty,

> Doctor Strange retrieves his magic cube from the Green Goblin and then prepares to activate the magic cube in order to return everyone back to their universes, but then a grenade that the Green Goblin had attached to the magic cube detonates and the huge explosion destroys the magic cube and it also does a lot of damage to the Statue of Liberty.

Why wasn't

> Doctor Strange

injured by this explosion?

Comment: If I was a wizard, the first thing I'd do is cover myself in magical spells that stop me getting hurt when I get hit with things

Comment: @Valorum:  ***If*** you were a wizard?   That sounds like something a secret wizard would say.

Comment: @Valorum, that makes sense although consider two things. One, in the movie Avengers: Infinity War, magical spells didn't protect Dr. Strange when Ebony Maw was pushing surgical blades into his face, and two, Dr. Strange's face got bruised and cut up during his battle with Thanos on the planet Titan.

Comment: @user57467 Pretty much like how Hulk was beaten into unconsciousness by Thanos even though he's supposed to be super strong (as in: it doesn't mean Hulk is weak; it merely means Thanos is that strong).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would actually be inclined to reverse the question, why would you suppose he would be hurt by the explosion in question?

From the very start of Stephen Strange becoming Doctor Strange in the MCU an emphasis has been put on him first learning to use, and then apply to combat situations, of his marquee spells - portals and energy shields. In every situation where a threat is present the familiar yellow round shields are immediately drawn and a defensive posture is taken.

It takes no leap of the imagination, nor does it need to be shown on camera, that in a highly dangerous combat situation as this he would have ample defensive spells and measures in place to react instantly to any threat.

Comment: Great answer! +1

Comment: @JdW, as I pointed out to Valorum in the comments above, defensive spells apparently didn't protect him from being physically injured by Ebony Maw and Thanos in the movie Avengers: Infinity War.